# Implementing Up button in toolbar - working without java code

Tags: android, android-activity

I am learning android and I am playing around with *up* and *back* button.
According to the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/ancestral.html#up) implementing *up* requires the following:

1- declare parent activity in the manifest
2- `getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);` in `onCreate`
3- overriding `onOptionsItemSelected` and processing the case of `android.R.id.home`

The Up button seems to work fine just by doing step one.
why are steps 2 and 3 necessary?

I am using `AppCompat`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`onOptionsItemSelected` callback is called every time user touches any of toolbar icons, including those on the right.

> overriding onOptionsItemSelected and processing the case of
>   android.R.id.home

will let you check the `id` of pressed options button and react to user request by executing some code. In case the `id` is equal `android.R.id.home`, just return from `onOptionsItemSelected` method.

[Here](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/menus.html#RespondingOptionsMenu) is an example from Android documentation.

Comment: I understand how `onOptionsItemSelected` works. I am asking because up navigation is working even without overriding it. so why did the documentation mentione it?

Comment: In that particular part of documentation they show you how to handle Up navigation in case the activity was started let's say from a push notification, and does not have an actual parent activity created and lying below it. That's why you need to specify the parent activity name. Parent activity will be created when user presses Up.

Comment: when you say "does not have a parent activity" do you mean no parent declared in the manifest file? or do you mean there is no instance of the parent activity running?

Comment: Last one: "no instance of the parent activity running". Let's say you have a simple app with a list of orders. When you click on a single order, a child activity containing order details is displayed. It also has an Up button leading back to orders list. Now, let's imagine the app is not running and a push notification with some updates about a particular order arrives. When user clicks the notification, he gets immediately to order details screen (there is no orders list activity created yet). But there is still an Up button, which when pressed, will lead to `parent activity` - orders list.